# How do I open a Firefox page with batch, and setting the link based on a text file's text?

Tags: firefox, batch-file

I've spent at least two hours guessing and looking around google for a way to do this. I got this far:

```
set A = C: \Users\Owner\Desktop\OutputFiles\LinkToHat.txt
start firefox A
```

I'm trying to open firefox with the website being the link that is inside the LinkToHat.txt file. I only know Lua, so I figured it would load the variable's value, rather than the website "A". Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Accessing a "set" variable needs the variable name surrounded by '%'s, e.g. %A%.

```
set A=C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\OutputFiles\LinkToHat.txt
start firefox "%A%"
```

Double quotes are added to prevent problems incur by spaces in the variable. (No problem now but you may have a URL with spaces assigned to A later)

Comment: By the way, no need to add double-quotes when setting a variable even if the value contains spaces.  
`set B=C:\Documents and Settings\Owner\Deskop\a.html`
is okay.